# Инициализация статических объектов в С++

Tags: c++

Пусть есть программа:

```
int aaa;

class b {
    int bb;
public:
    b(){}
};

b bbb;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Как известно, перед стартом main в переменную "aaa" будет записан ноль.

Вопросы:

1. Будет ли записан ноль в поле "bb" объекта "bbb"?
2. Будет ли вызван пустой конструктор класса "b" для объекта "bbb"? Или транслятор выбрасывает вызовы пустых конструкторов?

P.S. Вопрос не праздный. Нужно понять, можно ли избежать принудительного обнуления статических объектов и тем самым ускорить старт функции main.

UPD1:

Видимо надо сделать пояснения.

Вопрос связан с работой встроенных систем. То есть таких систем, в которых код зашит в ПЗУ и стартует из ПЗУ. В таких системах нельзя проинициализировать статические переменные при загрузке, так как код живет в ПЗУ, а в ОЗУ по старту лежит мусор. То есть никакие

```
bbb:
  .zero 4
aaa:
  .zero 4
```

в таких системах не прокатывают. И именно что до main должен запускаться отдельный код для обнуления статических переменных. Вместе с тем, если код для обнуления статических переменных работает слишком долго, то это тоже плохо. Как-то я общался с разработчиками систем защиты в энергетике. У них было требование, чтобы защита начинала работать после подачи питания не позднее чем через полпериода промышленной частоты в 50 Гц , то есть не позднее, чем 10 миллисекунд (чтобы отключить оборудование если на линии висит КЗ). Если питание подано, а процессор вместо работы заполняет нулями статические переменные, то это не очень хорошо.

Поэтому возник вопрос - как управлять процессом обнуления статических переменных и можно ли это делать с помощью классов с пустыми конструкторами. Похоже, что нельзя, во всяком случае для GCC и clang.

Comment: Гм. **Кода**, который присваивает значение переменной `aaa`, в программе как такового не будет.

Comment: @Harry Код будет, но от скрыт от программиста. Если поглядеть ассемблерный листинг, то видно, что перед вызовом main транслятор добавляет код, который забивает нулями секцию статических переменных. На это уходит время, особенно если в программе много статических переменных. Вопрос в том, будет ли экземпляр класса "bbb" включен в секцию статических переменных, если у него есть свой конструктор? И второй вопрос - будет ли вызван пустой конструктор?

Comment: Интересный вариант. Обычно просто значения сразу идут в сегменте данных, типа `_DATA SEGMENT
?b@@3HA DD 01H     ; b
?c@@3HA DD 02H     ; c
?d@@3HA DD 03H     ; d
?e@@3HA DD 04H     ; e
_DATA ENDS` - по крайней мере так поступает VC++.

Comment: @Harry В свое время я ковырял BC 5.0 для DOS. Там был отдельный код, который забивал нулями секцию статических переменных.

Comment: Ну как минимум сойдемся на том, что все зависит от компилятора :)

Comment: @Harry Но вопрос о том, будет ли запущен пустой конструктор, все равно остается. Вобщем-то как и вопрос будет ли проинициализирован нулями объект у которого есть конструктор.

Comment: "Как известно, перед стартом main в переменную "aaa" будет записан ноль." Ошибка. Переменная не обязана инициализироваться компилятором. Её значение - undefined - неопределено явно.

Comment: ну согласно https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/olVw1Z всё и так неплохо)

Comment: @pavel А вот при инициализирующем значении может быть как хорошо, так и плохо... https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WIwecT - словом, все зависит от конкретного компилятора. Но в самом деле - гарантируется ли 0 для `bb` стандартом? Понятно, что будет вызван конструктор, но будет ли перед этим обнулена память?...

Comment: @Harry самое интересное, что если убрать пустой конструктор, то в этой же ссылке нет лишнего вызова.

Comment: @Harry https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xpjzhY у меня вопрос. почему e и g дают одинаковый код, но b отличается. gcc бага?

Comment: @pavel У `b` нет явного конструктора - думаю, дело в этом?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 в примере нет ни одой статичной переменной. Так что ошибка

Comment: @Евгений Борисов Не ошибка. "aaa" и "bbb" это статические переменные.

Comment: Попробуйте запись вроде `b bbb = {0,};` для явного указания инициализировать в ноль, вдруг для класса тоже прокатит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут многое отдается на откуп реализации. В приведенном примере переменные никак не используются, а их инициализация не имеет побочных эффектов, соответственно они могут быть спокойно выкинуты компилятором. Если же они все-таки используются то

1. стандарт диктует, что статическая инициализация (в т.ч. обнуление) происходит строго до начала динамической инициализации:

> **6.8.3.2 Static initialization [basic.start.static]**
>   2 ... All static initialization strongly happens before (6.8.2.1) any
>   dynamic initialization.

2. а динамическая инициализация происходит строго до первого использования какой-либо переменной из той же единицы трансляции, причем это может происходить в неопределенный момент уже после начала выполнения `main`:

> **6.8.3.3 Dynamic initialization of non-local variables [basic.start.dynamic]**
>   4 It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static
>   storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly
>   happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the
>   same translation unit as the variable to be initialized. 55 It is implementation-defined in which threads and
>   at which points in the program such deferred dynamic initialization occurs.